# Does a *-dev package always contain all the files of the core package?

Tags: debian, package-management, packages

Many packages in the Debian repositories have two versions: the core package and a "dev" version of it (suffixed with `-dev`).

My question is, does a repo's `-dev` package always contain all of the files that the core package does? And, if so, would I only need the `-dev` package?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: The -dev packages should contain sources and usually information on how to compile/work with those sources, but they should not contain binary files. Unless you really know what you're doing, using the binary files is recommended over compiling from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incorrect, the *-dev packages generally contain more documentation, binary archive files, and header files.....any information that might be of use in a compilation and debug setting.  Non *-dev packages generally contain the basic commands, and the shared libraries.